# How To Find Dulpicate Row in Excel And Update A column with Status As its Duplicate

Tags: c#, excel, rpa

An excel having clolumns  bank account number , From Date , To Date and Status

if there is any duplicate vallues occured like Three columns bank account number , From Date , To Date Are Same ( See Below Example) then we need to update the status column as Duplicate , If two columns are same and and Third columns is different then its not a duplicate value if and only if the three columns are same then only we need to update the status.

```
Bank Account Number           From Date            To Date         Status

    123456789                 22-08-2006         01-10-2007

    123456789                 03-07-2010          05-09-2010

    123456789                 22-08-2006         01-10-2007       Duplicate 

    123456789                 22-08-2006         01-11-2007

    423823157                 30-09-2015          09-09-2017

    123456789                 22-08-2006         01-10-2007       Duplicate

    423823157                30-09-2015          09-09-2017       Duplicate 

    423823157                30-09-2016           08-09-2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the following solution online:

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1028584/How-to-find-duplicate-data-in-the-EXCEL-File-in-cs

```
var qry =  from p in tableName
           group p by p.columnNameinto grp
           where grp.Count() > 1
           select grp;

foreach (var product in qry)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Found!");
}
```

Hope this helps.